# How to show that $Hom(U,Hom(V,W)) \simeq Bil(U,V,W)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> Let $U,V,W$ be vectorspcaes. Show that $Hom(U,Hom(V,W)) \simeq Bil(U,V,W)$ via the isomorphism
> $$G: T(u,v) \mapsto T(u)(v)$$
> for all $T \in Hom(U,Hom(V,W))$, $u \in U$ and $v \in V$.

I am a bit confused by the definition of $T$. I realise that we can rewrite $T$ as

$$T(u,v) = T(u,f(v))$$

, where $f \in Hom(V,W)$, but I do not understand how we can deduce the properties of bilinearity from here. For example: I do not get why for a scalar $\lambda$ it should holds that $$T(\lambda u, v) = \lambda T(u,v).$$

Could you please give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}\newcommand{\bil}{\operatorname{Bil}}$You are worrying about the wrong thing, perhaps. $T$ is not defined, it is given. It is standing for any element of $\hom(U,\hom(V,W))$ which in this context means:

> Any such $T$ is linear, where $\hom(V,W)$ has the natural pointwise linear structure. That means $T(\lambda a+\lambda’b)$ is the linear mapping $v\mapsto\lambda T(a)(v)+\lambda’ T(b)(v)$.

What *is* defined is $G$, and we wish $G(T)$ to be a valid element of $\bil(U,V;W)$ for any $T$. Note that the above linearity of $T$ is precisely the statement: $$G(T)(\lambda a+\lambda’b,v)=T(\lambda a+\lambda’b)(v)=\lambda G(T)(a,v)+\lambda’ G(T)(b,v)$$So $G(T)$ is always linear in the first variable. We want to show it linear in the second variable too.

For that, I hint that $T(u)\in\hom(V,W)$ means $v\mapsto T(u)(v)$ is linear, for any fixed $u\in U$.

You need to satisfy yourself that $G(T)$ is always bilinear, and moreover find some function $H:\bil(U,V;W)\to\hom(U,\hom(V,W))$ that is inverse to $G$. As a bonus, show that both $G,H$ are linear functions so that we can call the following (natural) isomorphism an isomorphism of vector spaces: $$\hom(U,\hom(V,W))\cong\bil(U,V;W)$$Otherwise known (I think) as an instance of the tensor-hom adjunction.